# jQuery version conflicts - how to manage?

Tags: jquery, api, wordpress, hook

I made a Wordpress Plugin which includes a jQuery file. Now I've got the problem, that people who use my plugin may have a different jQuery Version on their Wordpress Blogs, so what shall I do to manage that? My plugin often doesn't work with 'other' jQuery Versions.

Maybe there is anyone who is addicted with the wordpress api. Maybe there are some hooks I didn't know (this is my first plugin). I will be pleased if these ones can have a short look in my sources:
http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/slide2comment/

Answer (score 0):

You should load your CSS and JS files using wp_enqueue_script and wp_enqueue_style instead of printing them as a hook on wp_print_style. This will ensure that you don't load a script that another plugin also loads.

http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_enqueue_script